# What is the difference between using который or какой?

Tags: грамматика

It seems like they both mean "which."  I know the combination of такой (же)…какой implies similarity, so is that the basic difference?  In other words, does using какой over который in a sentence imply some sort of similarity in the things being discussed?

Comment: About "такой (же)…какой", this form is not used widely (not sure if it is used at all). If you want to compare things and show their similarity in some property - it is "такой же...как" . "Он такой же умный, как и ты" - "He is as smart as you are". As for your example, you can say "Он такой же обаятельный, как и умный", here you compare two qualities o the same person: "He is as charming as he is smart" (not sure how to say it correctly in English). But it sounds more modern and better if you use brief forms and "так... как" - "Он так же обаятелен, как и умён".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Который" is used when there is a specific set of objects, and you want to choose one:

> **Который**.
>
> 1. Какой по порядку, по счёту?
> 2. Какой именно, какой из нескольких? отт. Кто именно, кто из нескольких?
> 3. Употребляется как союзное слово, присоединяя изъяснительные и определительные придаточные предложения.

So, it is possible to answer "- Который тебе понравился? - Первый". Or "- Который? - Этот"

"- Здесь есть синий, красный и фиолетовый плащи. Который тебе понравился? - Синий." Note that in the last example the "blue one" is one of the possible choices.

"Какой" is more abstract - this is a question about some qualities:

> **КАКО́Й**, какая, какое, мест. 1. вопросительное. Обозначает вопрос о качестве и свойстве. К какому выводу вы пришли? Какой ваш любимый цвет? Какая сегодня погода?

Basically "какой" in many cases can be used instead of "который", but "который" always means that there is a set of possible options, while answering on "какой" you may talk about imaginary things or about options that are currently not present.

> -- Какой смартфон бы ты купил?
>
> -- Я бы купил смартфон, который можно неделю не заряжать.

---

As Higstaker mentioned in comment, the 3rd meaning that both "which" and "который" have in common, but is not present in "какой" is "союзное слово, присоединяя изъяснительные и определительные придаточные предложения":

> Smartphone **which** costs less. = Смартфон **который** стоит меньше.
>
> A comission was created **which** began to investigate the accident. = Создана комиссия, **которая** приступила к расследованию обстоятельств катастрофы.

You cannot use "какая" or "какой" in these examples.

Comment: You may also mention the use of "который" as in "Физика - это наука, которая изучает..." ("Physics is a science that studies...")

Comment: @Highstaker this actually is an example of a relative clause.